# Implementing Distinct Sign In and Sign Up Views with @supabase/auth-ui-react

Tags: next.js, supabase, next.js13

I'm working with `@supabase/auth-ui-react`, and I'm trying to implement different types of authentication views, specifically for Sign In and Sign Up. I've looked at the [documentation](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/auth-ui), but I couldn't find details on how to specify different types of views for these specific functionalities.

Here's the code for the auth form I did now to use a magic link:

```js
import { Auth } from '@supabase/auth-ui-react'
import { ThemeSupa } from '@supabase/auth-ui-shared'
import { createClientComponentClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'
import { Database } from '../types/supabase';

export default function AuthForm() {
  const supabase = createClientComponentClient<Database>()

  return (
    <Auth
      supabaseClient={supabase}
      view="magic_link"
      appearance={{ theme: ThemeSupa }}
      theme="dark"
      showLinks={false}
      providers={[]}
      redirectTo="http://localhost:3000/auth/callback"
    />
  )
}
```

And here's the code for the page where I implemented the `AuthForm`:

```js
import AuthForm from './auth-form'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-6">
        <h1 className="text-black dark:text-white header">Supabase Auth + Storage</h1>
        <p className="text-black dark:text-gray-300">
          Experience our Auth and Storage through a simple profile management example. Create a user
          profile and upload an avatar image. Fast, simple, secure.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="col-6 auth-widget">
        <AuthForm />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I want to create distinct views for Sign In and Sign Up, but I'm having trouble understanding how to do this with the `@supabase/auth-ui-react` package. Does anyone know where I can find more detailed documentation or examples on how to implement these views? Any guidance on what I might be missing or doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit up to interpretation as of what "view" means in this context, however I will try to cover both possibilities.

1. If you just meant to ask how to literally change the view, then you can use the `view` prop set to `sign_in` or `sign_up` instead of `magic_link`. See more [here](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/auth-ui#supported-views). Otherwise, read further.
2. If you want to toggle between views (as in - switch from `view="sign_up"` to `view="sign_in"`) in a *controlled* way: It would be great if there were a handler for `onViewChange` so one could update different things depending on the current view. Unfortunately, at the time I'm writing this, there is no such thing out of the box. Even in the example provided in the documentation, the switch is done using a custom `select`: [here is a link](https://github.com/supabase/auth-ui/blob/main/examples/react/src/App.tsx).

Based on this, the solution I suggest is keeping `showLinks={false}` and add your own links / buttons instead - this way you can handle what you want to show and not show depending on the current state, and the view you're displaying as well, like so:

```js
const [view, setView] = useState<ViewType>('sign_in');

return (
<>
  <h1>{viewToMessageMap[view].title}</h1>

  <Auth view={view} supabaseClient={supabaseClient} magicLink={true} showLinks={false} />

  {view === 'sign_up' && (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setView('sign_in');
      }}
    >
      Already have an account? Sign in
    </button>
  )}
  {view === 'sign_in' && (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setView('magic_link');
        }}
      >
        Send a magic link email
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setView('forgotten_password');
        }}
      >
        Forgot your password?
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setView('sign_up');
        }}
      >
        Don't have an account? Sign up
      </button>
    </>
  )}
</>
);
```

This is a minimal example of how you can toggle between Sign In and Sign Up in place. It's the same principle for the other views as well. You can use links instead of buttons if you'd rather have separate pages for each view.
Hope this answers your question!